# Python dataframe_image results in SyntaxError: not a PNG file

Tags: python, dataframe, export, png

Good day. I used to have a normally working code which exports styled dataframe as a PNG. For some reason now it doesn't work except for certain machines used by my fellow coworkers. I suspect iit is somehow relevant to the latest windows or Chrome updates but I am not sure.

**Sample code**:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

my_array = np.array([[11,22,33],[44,55,66]])

df = pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns = ['Column_A','Column_B','Column_C'])

df=df.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'black',
'color': 'white'})
display(df)

dfi.export(df, 'Test.png', table_conversion='chrome')

**Received error**:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Anato\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 13, in 
dfi.export(df, 'Test.png', table_conversion='chrome')

File "C:\Users\Anato\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image_pandas_accessor.py", line 24, in export
dpi=None

File "C:\Users\Anato\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image_pandas_accessor.py", line 73, in _export

File "C:\Users\Anato\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataframe_image_screenshot.py", line 167, in run
max_crop = int(img.shape[1] * 0.15)

File "", line 40, in take_screenshot_override
img = mimage.imread(buffer)

File "C:\Users\Anato\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1541, in imread
with img_open(fname) as image:

File "C:\Users\Anato\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 121, in **init**
self._open()

File "C:\Users\Anato\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 677, in _open
raise SyntaxError("not a PNG file")

File "", line unknown
SyntaxError: not a PNG file

Searched the web and found no answer that could help. Tried udating packages and python itself. I believe it has to do with latest system updates but found no solution for over a week.

Comment: Also tried reverting dataframe_image  to older versions and it didn't help either

Comment: Last time my windows was updated on 14.01.2023 and I suspect that this is what caused the issue but not 100% certain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error exporting styled dataframes to image, "SyntaxError: not a PNG file" using dataframe\_image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75135530/error-exporting-styled-dataframes-to-image-syntaxerror-not-a-png-file-using)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following worked:

1. Update windows to the latest version
2. Update conda